# Contains in SQL Server 2012 not returning result as expected

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where `CONTAINS` is not returning results as expected.

Below are the queries which I have tried. I have a scenario in my app where a user can provide input with single quote or without a single quote.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 
WHERE CONTAINS(column1,'''abc''')
```

I am getting result as expected for this query with expression abc.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 
WHERE CONTAINS(column1,'''xyz''')
```

I am not getting result as expected for this query with expression xyz.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 
WHERE CONTAINS(column1,'xyz')
```

I am getting result as expected for this query with expression xyz.

Comment: `Contains` does a full-text search - is this what you intend, or should you look at `charindex` instead?

Comment: i need a full text search. Only issue i am facing is for certain expressions, if user provides with a single quote CONTAINS is not returning results. But if the same expression is provided without single quote it is working fine.

Comment: So what are the values in the column1 that you're testing against. Maybe setup a SQLFiddle to show the full problem.

Comment: column1 contains AlphaNumeric values. I cannot setup a SQLFiddle as it is my workstation.

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is a web based thing, nothing to setup.  Is there a reason you aren't just using `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause?  What are you getting/looking to get out of full-text search that a simple `LIKE` wouldn't satisfy?